# jQuery image src fadeOut fadeIn effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I have a problem with this code. It simply does not work. The process ends on fadinOut the image. I'm beginner in JS.

The code:

```
$(".intro_lg").click(function() {
$(".intro_lg").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    var path = "http://website.com/img/intro2.png";
    $(".intro_lg").attr("src", path);
}).fadeIn(1000);
return false;
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It suppose to fadeOut the image after I click on it, then change its URL to the one given in `var path`, and then fadeIn the image with new src URL.

It stops on fadeOut, I don't even know if it changes the URL.

Comment: Do you have ".intro_lg" class on another html elements?

Comment: No, It appears only once in whole html block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running your code when the page is ready using `.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".intro_lg").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
      var path = "http://website.com/img/intro2.png";
      $(this).attr("src", path);
    }).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

And rather than repeating your selectors, use `this` instead.

**[Here is an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n8dx3z7f/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do not use

```
$(".intro_lg").fadeOut
```

use

```
$(this).fadeOut
```

because ".intro_lg" is class and can be on another html elements.
And better way for this is not replace image "src", but hide and show images(exists in dom), because image loading by browser is take time.
for example html:

```
<img src="path1" class="intro_lg" alt=""/>
<img src="path2" class="intro_lg" alt="" style="display: none;"/>
```

Script:

```
$(".intro_lg").click(function() {
$(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(".intro_lg").next().fadeIn(1000);
});
return false;
});
```